# Adding elements in a list *in expectation*

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, algorithms

Suppose $_1,…,_$ are lists with $n$ elements each. We use a fully independent hash function ℎ to compute a value for each element of each list. (We suppose the hash function returns a value uniformly at random from $[^c]$ for some large constant $c$. Note also that two elements $x$, and $y$ where $x = y$ has $ℎ()=ℎ()$). Let $_1,\ldots,_$ be sublists with the smallest $$ elements *by computed hash value* in each list and let $_1 = L_1$. Define more $$s by:
$$
_{+1}=
\begin{cases}
_\cup_ & \text{if }|_\cap _|</,\\
_ & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

What size of $$ will ensure *in expectation* that
$c_1\left(\frac{|C_i \cap M_i|}{|M_i|}\right) \leq \frac{|_\cap_|}{|L_i|} \leq c_2\left(\frac{|C_i \cap M_i|}{|M_i|}\right)$ for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$; I am happy if this works for any constants (e.g. $c_1 = 0.5$ and $c_2 = 2$).

I am looking to minimize the size of $X$.

Comment: I can't quite parse what you are asking. What does it mean to ensure "in expectation" that $V<r$ if $A$, where $V$ is a random variable and $A$ is an event? (Also, just to check, I guess you mean that $C_1=L_1$, not just that $C_1$ contains $L_1$?)

Comment: @JamesMartin I fixed the problem statement. Does it make more sense now?